# Open a single accordion in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem, I'm generating several accordions dynamically. But my problem is that when trying to open one, they all open. How can I solve that?

https://plnkr.co/edit/BQ4yQkEtiDrnhISozlOe?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
 <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="status.open">
  <uib-accordion-heading>
    {{faq.pregunta}} <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
  </uib-accordion-heading>
  {{faq.respuesta}}
</div>
```

```
$scope.faqs=[
 {"pregunta": "pregunta1", "respuesta": "respuesta1"},
 {"pregunta": "pregunta2", "respuesta": "respuesta2"},
 {"pregunta": "pregunta3", "respuesta": "respuesta3"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `is-open="status.open"` is all tied to the same boolean value within your `$scope.status` object. You'd need to instead add a property such as `open` to each of your `$scope.faqs` collection items to indicate which individual `uib-accordion-group` should be open at one time:

```
$scope.faqs=[
    {"pregunta": "pregunta1", "respuesta": "respuesta1", "open": true },
    {"pregunta": "pregunta2", "respuesta": "respuesta2", "open": false},
    {"pregunta": "pregunta3", "respuesta": "respuesta3", "open": false}
];
```

Then you'd need to target the respective `faq` within the `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="faq.open">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            {{faq.pregunta}} <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': faq.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !faq.open}"></i>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        {{faq.respuesta}}
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also use the `faq.open` within the ng-repeat with your `ng-class` declarations for the chevrons.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/syK9nvWlkJyBEX11Uoez?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Why not just use `is-open="faq.open"`? Much simpler, more logical, and will work fine even if the faqs is filtered or ordered by a filter in the ng-repeat.